Cypress not installing binary in gitlab pipeline CI
I'm trying to install cypress in my gitlab pipeline. It works fine on my local (windows).
my gitlab yml file:
CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER: $PROJECT_DIR/.cache/Cypress

cache:
  paths:
    - ~/.cache/Cypress
    - .cache/Cypress
    - $PROJECT_DIR/.cache/Cypress



e2e-test:
  image: $CYPRESS_IMG
  script:
    - export HTTP_PROXY=[my proxy]
    - export HTTPS_PROXY=[my proxy]
    - npm config set registry [my registry]
    - npm set strict-ssl false
    - export CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=$PROJECT_DIR/.cache/Cypress
    - export CYPRESS_CRASH_REPORTS=1
    - npm ci
    - npm install cypress
    - ./node_modules/.bin/cypress install --force
    - npx cypress run
  tags: ['linux']

The output:

I've already tried to cache everything, but even after running npm install cypress, the cache folder is not created. Other things I tried:

set the artifacts;
remove the proxy;
remove registry;
basically everything in this documentation: https://on.cypress.io/not-installed-ci-error


I'm in the same situation, it seems that the cypress package isn't installing correctly. I've tested the Viktor Nedelko solution, but it seems that the Cypress installation starts but doesn't finish...
In my Gitlab CI pipeline I have the following log:

On another project I'm using Jenkins and in my pipeline the equivalent log when it works looks like this:


This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review

I've had similar issues with yarn, and I ended up finding the solution in this documentation on troubleshooting installation, stating that you need to separately install the cypress binary by running yarn cypress install. In your case I think it would be npx cypress install instead of npm install cypress.
That should solve it, and also decreases the items you need to cache. I decided to not cache it whatsoever to save some CI time. Hope this helps.
